# Cost function not decreasing in gradient descent implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, gradient, linear-regression

I am trying implemented batch gradient descent in C language. The problem is, my cost function increases dramatically in every turn and I am not able to understand what is wrong. I checked my code several times and it seems to me that I coded exactly the formulas. Do you have any suggestions or ideas what might be the wrong in the implementation?

My data set is here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Housing
And I reference these slides for the algorithm (I googled this): http://asv.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/uploads/document/file_link/527/TMI04.2_linear_regression.pdf

I read the data set correctly into the main memory. Below part shows how I store the data set information in main memory. It is straight-forward.

```
//Definitions
#define NUM_OF_ATTRIBUTES   13
#define NUM_OF_SETS     506
#define LEARNING_RATE   0.07

//Data holder
struct data_set_s
 {
   double x_val[NUM_OF_SETS][NUM_OF_ATTRIBUTES + 1];
   double y_val[NUM_OF_SETS];
   double teta_val[NUM_OF_ATTRIBUTES + 1]; 
 };

//RAM
struct data_set_s data_set;
```

Teta values are initialized to 0 and x0 values are initialized to 1.

Below section is the hypothesis function, which is the standart polynomial function.

```
double perform_hypothesis_a(unsigned short set_index)
{
double  result;
int     i;

result = 0;
for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ATTRIBUTES + 1; i++)
   result += data_set.teta_val[i] * data_set.x_val[set_index][i];

return result; 
}
```

Below section is the cost function.

```
double perform_simplified_cost_func(double (*hypothesis_func)(unsigned short))
{
double result, val;
int     i;

result = 0;
for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_SETS; i++)
{
   val = hypothesis_func(i) - data_set.y_val[i];
   result += pow(val, 2);
}

result = result / (double)(2 * NUM_OF_SETS);
return result;
```

}

Below section is the gradient descent function.

```
double perform_simplified_gradient_descent(double (*hypothesis_func)(unsigned short))
{
double  temp_teta_val[NUM_OF_ATTRIBUTES + 1], summation, val;
int     i, j, k;

for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ATTRIBUTES + 1; i++)
   temp_teta_val[i] = 0; 

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) //assume this is "while not converged"
 {
   for(j = 0; j < NUM_OF_ATTRIBUTES + 1; j++)
    {
      summation = 0;
      for(k = 0; k < NUM_OF_SETS; k++)
       {
         summation += (hypothesis_func(k) - data_set.y_val[k]) * data_set.x_val[k][j];   
       }

      val = ((double)LEARNING_RATE * summation) / NUM_OF_SETS);
      temp_teta_val[j] = data_set.teta_val[j] - val;
    }

    for(j = 0; j < NUM_OF_ATTRIBUTES + 1; j++)
     {
      data_set.teta_val[j] = temp_teta_val[j];
     }  

    printf("%lg\n ", perform_simplified_cost_func(hypothesis_func));
 }

return 1;
}
```

While it seems correct to me, when I print the cost function at the end of the every gradient descent, it goes like: 1.09104e+011, 5.234e+019, 2.51262e+028, 1.20621e+037...

Comment: Have you ruled out a sign error?